What is the canonical way to intercept HTTP requests to external URL in a perl test?
The following piece of code will make a call to the URL embedded in the XML document:
use 5.020;
use XML::LibXML ();

XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => <<'EOF' );
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE foo [<!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "http://webhook.site/<unique-token>">]>
<foo>&xxe;</foo>
EOF

I would like to add a test that fails when parsing XML strings result in calls to embedded URLs. My thought was to intercept calls to specified URLs and pass or fail the test accordingly:
use 5.020;
use Test2::V0;

ok makes_no_http_requests {
    # example code above
}, 'should not make any HTTP requests';

done_testing;

sub makes_no_http_requests {
    # how would this be implemented?
}

Is there a canonical way to do this in perl?

Why do you want to intercept the URL? Is it just counting? There are plenty of reasons why you'd intercept this, but the reason might suggest the solution. Fort example, most Mojolicious stuff is event driven, so you could add an event hook to Mojo::UserAgent to do whatever you want.

I'm trying to test a fix for an XXE vulnerability within a perl test. At the moment I have to monitor a separate service to see the vulnerability in action. I wondered if I could cut that down to running a single unit test.

So, you want to test if there was an access from your program to a website it should not access? What in your program would make a web request (curl, LWP, Mojo)?

Yes. XML::LibXML::load_xml is what is making the web request when it parses suitably compromised XML (e.g. https://gist.github.com/j1n3l0/f7fc6e37fa32ce0d87571608749e0c38).

I've been thinking about this and have no good answer for the question as asked. However, it seems you can't get around this without major surgery in XML::LibXML. I think my first stab might be to back up a step and look at the XML before I let LibXML have a go at it. That seems a catch 22 since to look at the XML, you have to look at it. But, you might be able to look at the DOCTYPE with a regex then compare the URLs to a white list. Sorry we don't have a better answer.

I don't know if it's canonical or not, but here's now I do it with my Mock::Sub library.
First, move the actual get routine to its own sub so you can mock it:
package App;

sub function {
    my ($url) = @_;

    get_url($url);
}

sub get_url {
    my ($url) = @_;
    # do something
}

1;

Then mock the get_url() sub in your test script:
use warnings;
use strict;

use Mock::Sub;
use Test::More;

use lib '.';

use App;

my $m = Mock::Sub->new;

my $get_sub = $m->mock('App::get_url');

App::function('https://perlmonks.org');
App::function('https://perlmonks.org');

is $get_sub->called, 1, "get_url() called ok";
is $get_sub->called_count, 2, "...and it was called twice ok";

done_testing();

Output:
ok 1 - get_url() called ok
ok 2 - ...and it was called twice ok
1..2


In this instance I unfortunately cannot isolate the GET request, which is why I am trying to intercept the HTTP request. I want to understand how such a thing is done in perl. e.g. in node I would use the nock library (https://github.com/nock/nock/tree/main).

@j1n3l0 I honestly don't know whether Perl has something that can literally trap a network traffic request like this. I usually mock the function/method that does the work, and beyond what I've shown in the example, return from the mock object exactly what I would be expecting from whatever is making the call. (eg. Success, Code, Data).
Can you show in your post exactly what you're trying to wrap around? Are you testing the entire App::function, or just innards of it?

Hopefully the updates to the question are more helpful.
